# Pin Windows Sticky Notes on top

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, sticky-notes

How can I make the Sticky Notes pin on top of everything else? They don't seem to be real windows. There is no way to cascade/tile them either.

Comment: I am using [simple sticky notes](https://www.simplestickynotes.com/) which supports this. (I can't add an answer as of now).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Another half baked idea from Microsoft, you cannot keep them on top or tile them. You would need to look for a 3rd party sticky note application that has more features.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-sticky-notes-place-on-top-of-all-windows/b1d90084-83ac-4355-b605-dfe7432e2cf6

Comment: Yes, some of the 3rd sticky notes apps are stickies, Hott Note, 7 sticky notes, Notezilla, TurboNote. Most of them support keeping sticky notes on top.

Comment: Confirmed both Hott Notes and Notezilla allow you to keep the note on top. However Notezilla is a MUCH better user experience.

Comment: Agreed. Notezilla seems to top the list.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `NIRCMD` tool. Download it here:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

then run this in the command line:

```
C:\> nircmd.exe win settopmost class Sticky_Notes_Top_Window 1
```

or maybe:

```
C:\> nircmd.exe win settopmost title "Sticky Notes" 1
```

Comment: Note: You'll need to open the command prompt as an administrator.

Comment: This worked once for me and than stopped working

Answer (score 6):

While downloading a new tool to solve the issue is dicey, I found a great solution now in OneNote, open a side note, and keep it pinned. AND you get sync AND you get formatting, search, AND SCROLL (for which I had to download another tool!) etc etc which was ridiculously missing in sticky notes.

Comment: What's a side note, all I see is the option to add a quick note or add a new page in a notebook, neither of those stay on top of other windows

Comment: @Ghos3t: Open a new quick note, and then click on the bar on the top of the note window; the ribbon drops down. There's an 'Always on Top' option in the 'View' section; click that and it'll stay on top. Great answer!

Answer (score 5):

Turned out Sticky Notes is not supporting always on top now.

I'm using [WinTop](http://www.skybn.com/window-on-top/) to keep it on top and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

I totally recommend using dexpot to anyone, it will solve your problem no coding required, although it’s not only its sole purpose to make a window always on top. To make a window always on top, you can right click on the titlebar of the window and right click, select always on top. However, for the sticky notes, it’s a little irregular, so what i did was to set up a shortcut for it to be alt+t, so when i do alt-t, the window currently active will become “always on top” even the sticky notes! So yes, try it, it’s free, and will do alot more functions, like transparency, that you can always define a shortcut to make it easier.
Cheers!

Download here:
http://dexpot.de/

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, Are you a salesmen for DexPot? you seem to be going for the hard sell here

Comment: Haha, I am sorry, I do sound like a salesperson. But no, I am just a long time user of dexpot. And, to be honest, dexpot is even free for non-commercial use, so it's not like there's any sales going on?

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite Windows Stickys but its just a simple program that requires no install and is just Sticky notes. It is set to be Always On Top or can be removed, nothing fancy. http://www.rndpro.com/downloads/notesontop.zip

Comment: This is a good app, but I quite dislike the design. Have an upvote though

Comment: bad link. 404 not found

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) has a functionality that allows you to set any window as always on top via a customizable keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to in another incomplete answer:

1. Install **Microsoft Powertoys** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) by running the Powershell command: `winget install Microsoft.PowerToys --source winget`.
2. Go to **Settings** in Powertoys, Select **Enable Always On Top** in the side menu and turn **On** (Default).
3. Once installed the default key-binding **CMD+CTRL+T** can be used to make any window always on top.

[image]

Job done, works great for a multitude of **Always on Top** requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 3rd party app [WindowTop](https://windowtop.info/) to `set top` any window.