# How to get Windows 7 sticky notes to appear on top after a "lock computer"

Tags: windows-7, sticky-notes

I would like the default Sticky Notes to appear in front in one of this cases:

- Each time a unlock my PC (using ctrl-alt-del and entering password)
- Regularly, say once every hour

Any ideas to how to do this?

Comment: Related: [Pin Windows Sticky Notes on top](http://superuser.com/questions/264942/pin-windows-sticky-notes-on-top)

Comment: This is what Outlook tasks are for.

Comment: @surfasb, I got overflow on my  outlook task list, so instead of actually completing all of my tasks, I try to find ways of prioritizing the most important ones :-)